# How can i add more table fields on already developed Django User table Database

Tags: python, django, django-models, user-mode-linux

I want to add more fields in User Data table so Please Explain the right method to done this.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is very simple, in your models.py in the User model just simply
add another field,

> example:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.IntegerField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

> lets add the field email:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.IntegerField()
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

> then run this command in your terminal:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

> and it will display the alter you are about to make and then run the
>   command:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

and the new field will be added.I hope this helps you

Cheers!